# Bulk column DROP in snowflake --- syntax for WHERE first character of column LIKE '_'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, wildcard

A Snowflake table has been populated with 2000+ columns due to each property being sent as a KEY instead of VALUE.

Need to drop these columns.

All of them begin with `_` e.g. '`_ASD3234E2`

To test my syntax will be correct for the final ALTER TABLE command, I'm first trying a SHOW COLUMNS command.

`SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '_%' IN TABLE DELIVERY_VIEW_DETAIL;`

This is showing all columns in the table still though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Austin mentioned as well, it needs to be escaped -

```
SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '\\_%' IN TABLE TRANS_1 ;
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| table_name | schema_name | column_name |
|------------+-------------+-------------+
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL1       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL2       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL3       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL4       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Without escape -

```
SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '_%' IN TABLE TRANS_1 ;
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| table_name | schema_name | column_name |
|------------+-------------+-------------+
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | ID          |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL1       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL2       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL3       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL4       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Single escape -

```
SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '\_%' IN TABLE TRANS_1 ;
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| table_name | schema_name | column_name |
|------------+-------------+-------------+
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | ID          |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL1       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL2       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL3       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL4       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

All columns -

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE TRANS_1 ;
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| table_name | schema_name | column_name |
|------------+-------------+-------------+
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | ID          |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL1       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL2       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL3       |
| TRANS_1    | PUBLIC      | _COL4       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```